# Fetching Sharepoint list in webpart in Sharepoint 2016 SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, spfx, spfx-webparts

I have added one textbox to my web part now I want to display data from sharepoint list to this textbox how it can be done in SPFx(on-premise)?

Answer (score 2):

SPFx has a `spHttpClient` as a helper class to call **REST API** requests against SharePoint.

**Ex:** to get the list items from SharePoint List.

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Employee')/Items
```

---

To use `spHttpClient`, import it first from the ‘@microsoft/sp-http’ module.

```
import {  
  SPHttpClient  
} from '@microsoft/sp-http';
```

To get SharePoint list items, using REST API within the ‘GetSpListItemsWebPart’ class.

```
private _getListData(): Promise<ISPLists> {  
return this.context.spHttpClient.get(this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + `/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('EmployeeList')/Items`, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)  
    .then((response: Response) => {   
      debugger;  
      return response.json();  
    });  
}
```

Ref & more details at [Retrieve SharePoint List Items Using SharePoint Framework Development Model](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/retrieve-sharepoint-list-items-using-sharepoint-framework-development-model/)

See also, [SharePoint Framework: Retrieve and Display SharePoint List Items using REST API and React JS](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37948.sharepoint-framework-retrieve-and-display-sharepoint-list-items-using-rest-api-and-react-js.aspx)

Comment: I have done same but it is showing UNDEFINED in my webpart

Comment: Please edit your question, and add what you have done!

Comment: I have one client side web part using spfx, now I am trying to fetch values from sharepoint list to make it display on web part. The data is displaying but not coming in their respective columns as they are in sharepoint list. Also there is a column which have mutiple names, I want to fetch all those names in my web part. How it can be done?